# No Internet Access after restarting System in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

I am facing one problem with my system having Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (recently upgraded). Problem is Wifi is working but No Internet Access, I tried with

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

but after restarting the system these two lines are disabled automatically.

Please help me to resolve the problem
Thank you so much

Comment: in wich file you added the two lines ?

Comment: What does ```ping google.com``` and ```ping 1.1.1.1``` show? Also, as @cmak.fr said, in which file did you add this? please also show the output of ```ip addr``` and ```ifconfig -a``` ?

Comment: Hello cmak.fr, I added these lines to resolv.conf file after Wrote out and exit

Comment: Hello @VarunChhangani I checked google DNS its working properly and I added the 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 lines to DNS by switching to off  mode. Still NO Internet Connection.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu Desktop, the dns client setup should be done via network manager
You have to revert modifications in `resolv.conf` then setup the dns servers in the `gnome-control-center`


In the file `/etc/resolv.conf` replace the two lines

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

by the original

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Then, setup DNS servers in the Gnome Control Panel, WIFI section

```
# the panel can be opened with the command line or the gui
gnome-control-center wifi
```

[image]

Find your Wifi SSID, hit the cog, go to IPv4 tab
In the DNS section, switch Automatic to OFF. Enter the IP address of the DNS servers you want to use like this `8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4`

Comment: I Changed the DNS automatic to OFF and also I added these lines 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4. But no change in the response same No Internet Connection

Answer (score -2):

I was having same problem  <----(((newbie))) I did find that going into F9 and changing boot order to boot network first cured it. The network controller at first will have a exclamation mark beside it. Still move it to #1 of boot order... F10 and save...  WiFi should be able to see signals this time

Comment: Why are you using capslock?